# Deleting files on a mapped drive using c# and IIS

Tags: c#, file, iis, mapped-drive

I currently have a function on one of my Blazor pages that will allow a user to type in a file path and clear some files both on the users computer as well as mapped drives. This works through visual studio when I run it just fine. The problem is when I use IIS to host this application it no longer can delete these files using File.Delete( string of the path name ).
It still can delete files on the computer it's being hosted on but not any of the files of the other computers that I was able to delete in debug mode using visual studio 2022. I tried typing in the path name as both the drive it was mapped as (ex: R:\Users\test) and using the IP address (ex: \123.456.78.89\C:\Users\test) and neither did anything.

Is this possible using IIS? Do i have to change any of the settings for my application to be able to find and delete these files?

snippet of c# function just incase:

```
 public async Task ClearFiles()
    {
        var pathName = FileFilter.PathName;
        FileInfo[] files = SortFiles(pathName);

        try
        {
            if(FileFilter.Filter == "all")
            {
                //will clear all files based on the extension(s) entered
                foreach(var file in files)
                {
                    if(file.Extension == FileFilter.Extension || FileFilter.Extension == "all")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(file.ToString());
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                            Toast = Toast.Bad("Error deleting a file");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

.
.
.
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to show exact errors you are getting and what account that code runs under. (Obviously to delete a file account the code runs under must see the files and must have permissions to delete them - so providing account name for such issues is important. Depending on the actual account my may want to redact it before posting replacing domain/computer name with some more generic equivalent if that is information you don't want to disclose... also I'm 99% sure you'd have generic local account name in this case )

Comment: When your code is hosted on IIS, the application pool identity is used to access external resources. So, to access a remote file, you need a valid identity there as well as proper permissions set on the file. Mapped drives are not supported by IIS, so UNC paths must be used. Things work on VS because https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: The identity user on the application pool may not access other network paths/mapped drives. On the server where the drive is mapped, create an application pool and select a user who has access to the mapped drive in the identity field of the application pool and set Load User Profile to true, then assign that application pool to your application virtual directory.